# how to display an object in blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to learn Blazor, C#. I've created a website which calls a third party API and returns some information to the web page. It displays everything ok, expect for one item in my class. The item is a object, containing lots of information.

Here is the class

```
namespace learnc.Models
{


    public class BritishAirwaysModel
    {
        public Getba_Locationsresponse GetBA_LocationsResponse { get; set; }
    }

    public class Getba_Locationsresponse
    {
        public Country[] Country { get; set; }
    }

    public class Country
    {
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public object City { get; set; }
        
    }

}
```

In the Razor component, I have this code

```
       <tbody>
        @foreach (var ba in balocations.GetBA_LocationsResponse.Country)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@ba.CountryName.</td>
            <td>@ba.CountryCode</td>
            <td>@ba.City</td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        }

    </tbody>


</table>
```

When it renders on the screen, it get this for City,

```
{
    "GetBA_LocationsResponse": {
        "Country": [
            {
                "CountryName": "United Arab Emirates",
                "CountryCode": "AE",
                "City": [
                    {
                        "CityName": "Abu Dhabi",
                        "CityCode": "AUH",
                        "Position": {
                            "Latitude": 0,
                            "Longitude": 0
                        },
                        "Airport": {
                            "AirportName": "Abu Dhabi",
                            "AirportCode": "AUH",
                            "Position": {
                                "Latitude": 24.43,
                                "Longitude": 54.65
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "CityName": "Dubai",
                        "CityCode": "DXB",
                        "Position": {
                            "Latitude": 0,
                            "Longitude": 0
                        },
                        "Airport": {
                            "AirportName": "Dubai",
                            "AirportCode": "DXB",
                            "Position": {
                                "Latitude": 25.25,
                                "Longitude": 55.36
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "CountryName": "Antigua",
                "CountryCode": "AG",
                "City": {
                    "CityName": "Antigua",
                    "CityCode": "ANU",
                    "Position": {
                        "Latitude": 0,
                        "Longitude": 0
                    },
                    "Airport": {
                        "AirportName": "Antigua",
                        "AirportCode": "ANU",
                        "Position": {
                            "Latitude": 17.14,
                            "Longitude": -61.79
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "CountryName": "Albania",
                "CountryCode": "AL",
                "City": {
                    "CityName": "Tirana",
                    "CityCode": "TIA",
                    "Position": {
                        "Latitude": 0,
                        "Longitude": 0
                    },
                    "Airport": {
                        "AirportName": "Tirana",
                        "AirportCode": "TIA",
                        "Position": {
                            "Latitude": 41.41,
                            "Longitude": 19.72
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "CountryName": "Argentina",
                "CountryCode": "AR",
                "City": {
                    "CityName": "Buenos Aires",
                    "CityCode": "BUE",
                    "Position": {
                        "Latitude": 0,
                        "Longitude": 0
                    },
                    "Airport": {
                        "AirportName": "Buenos Aires",
                        "AirportCode": "EZE",
                        "Position": {
                            "Latitude": -34.82,
                            "Longitude": -58.54
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "CountryName": "Austria",
                "CountryCode": "AT",
                "City": [
                    {
                        "CityName": "Innsbruck",
                        "CityCode": "INN",
                        "Position": {
                            "Latitude": 0,
                            "Longitude": 0
                        },
                        "Airport": {
                            "AirportName": "Kranebitten",
                            "AirportCode": "INN",
                            "Position": {
                                "Latitude": 47.26,
                                "Longitude": 11.34
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What do I do so I can just display a couple of the items from the City object. For example, say I just want to display the CityName and CityCode.
What code do I write to loop for each of the City object and pull out of it just the CityName and CityCode.

Thanks
Russell

Comment: Why `public object City { get; set; }` ?

Comment: This isn't my API, it's a third party that's why its the way it is.

Answer (score 4):

It helps when you use better naming.

```
@foreach (var ba in balocations.GetBA_LocationsResponse.Country)
```

reads weird, Country is a singular word but apparently it is a list here. Try to rename things so that you get:

```
@foreach (var country in balocations.GetBA_LocationsResponse.Countries)
```

The same thing goes for City. In the JSon it is an array, so name it `Cities`.

And then it becomes clear that you have a choice to make: a `Country` (ba) has many `Cities` , what do you want to show?

A simple suggestion so that you see at least something:

```
    @foreach (var ba in balocations.GetBA_LocationsResponse.Country)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@ba.CountryName.</td>
        <td>@ba.CountryCode</td>
        <td>@ba.City.FirstOrDefault()?.Name</td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
```

---

OK, you posted some Json. It is irregular, some countries have 1

```
 "City": { ... },
```

while others have a list:

```
 "City": [{ ... },{ ... } ],
```

That confuses code generators.

The easiest way out is to copy/paste that response to a temp file, reduce it to just 1 country (with >= 2 cities). Make sure the Json is valid and generate the C# classes again.

There are also plenty of online Json tooling sites to help you analyze, validate and convert Json.

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work.<td>@ba.City.FirstOrDefault()?.Name</td>. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well, you are right "it doesn't work" isn't an answerable question. It's a statement. And if you want to help then help. If you want to just comment on peoples messages being pompous.carry on!!

Comment: This isn't a message board. Read [ask].